# Did not displayed anything on the Console thru Kafka Streaming

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am very new in Spark, Python & Kafka integration. I could not see anything printed on the console. Please advice. Appreciate your cooperation.

`zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`

`bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic test --broker-list localhost:9092`

`bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic test --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

**My code is**

```py
    import os
    import sys
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--conf spark.ui.port=4040 --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.0 pyspark-shell'
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
    from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
    import json
    sc = SparkContext(appName="streaming-test")
    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 60)
    kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, '127.0.0.1:2181', 'streaming-test', {'test':1})
    kafkaStream.pprint()
    ssc.start()  
    ssc.awaitTermination()
    Output is
    last couple of lines of output on console.
```

**Output is**

```
    0/09/30 14:21:50 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 36057. 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:36057 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36057, None) 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:36057 with 413.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36057, None) 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36057, None) 20/09/30 14:21:50 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 36057, None)
    Time: 2020-09-30 14:22:00
    Time: 2020-09-30 14:23:00
```

Comment: It looks like you are subscribing with `{'test':1}` only to the partition `1` of the topic test. By default, it probably only has one partition. Can you replace `{'test':1}` with `{'test':0}` and try again?

Comment: Hi Mikalai,  Thanks a lot for quick response and suggestion. I modified code with {'test':0} but I got now different errors as below. 
Command I used to run is as below – 
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 kafka_test_2.py
20/10/01 21:39:46 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 37307, None)
20/10/01 21:39:55 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Error starting receiver 0 - java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
 at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)

Comment: Hi Friends,  I put it back as a {'test':1} in the above code and so ERROR ReceiverTracker cleared  but  I am not able to display anything coming from Kafka stream.  Please help me here for very basic this use case.  Appreciate your cooperation.